# how to download data files on git using R

Tags: r, git

I have a data file on git that constantly gets updated/changed by our team, is there a way to download all versions/histories of the data file using R.

Thanks,

Comment: Using R? Why don't you download it using git?

Comment: The git2r package provides bindings to libgit.

Comment: @mkasberg, I am thinking about downloads data files and process them all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

As variant you can use `system` method and execute any git command using it:

```
system("git clone http://gitrepo.com")
```